# Python login to email server authentication error

Tags: python, email, authentication

I am on a Linux machine. My company has an email exchange server which is already configured. I am using a Python script to try to login to the email server so that I can send an email programmatically. Here is what I have so far -

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('email-0.abc.com', 25)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()    
server.login('abc/johndoe', 'pwd')
```

However, at the server.login command, I get an error as

```
raise SMTPException("No suitable authentication method found.")
SMTPException: No suitable authentication method found.
```

Anyone know what the problem is please?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You might need to switch to STARTTLS authentication. Here's an example that helped me.

[How To Send Email In Python Via SMTPLIB](http://www.mkyong.com/python/how-do-send-email-in-python-via-smtplib/)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your Mail Server is rejecting the plain Authentication method.

What server do you use?

If MS Exchange please see this article: http://www.exchangeinbox.com/article.aspx?i=93

Comment: Thanks very much, yes I am using MS Exchange, let me check out that article. Meanwhile, I also realised that I can send email without logging in - and that worked.                                             server.sendmail(sender, recipients,msg_txt)

Answer (score 1):

The Exchange server I was connecting to, required NTLM authentication, which is not supported by `smtplib` out of the box.

As of this writing (January 2022) and according to my modest research, the most maintained Python library that solves this problem, is [`pyspnego`](https://github.com/jborean93/pyspnego/). The following snippet was [provided by the library author](https://github.com/jborean93/pyspnego/issues/29#issuecomment-1016784012) and worked for me without any modifications:

```
import base64
import spnego

from smtplib import SMTPException, SMTPAuthenticationError


def ntlm_authenticate(smtp, username, password):
    auth = spnego.client(username, password, service="SMTP", protocol="ntlm")
    ntlm_negotiate = auth.step()

    code, response = smtp.docmd("AUTH", "NTLM " + base64.b64encode(ntlm_negotiate).decode())
    if code != 334:
        raise SMTPException("Server did not respond as expected to NTLM negotiate message")

    ntlm_challenge = base64.b64decode(response)
    ntlm_auth = auth.step(ntlm_challenge)
    code, response = smtp.docmd("", base64.b64encode(ntlm_auth).decode())
    if code != 235:
        raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. My case could be the different from yours but error is same as you mentioned.

In my scenario, I don't have to pass the username and password for authentication as server IP was added in white-list of SMTP mail server. And I was passing username and password for authentication which was giving me the error stating "No suitable authentication method found."

This may not be the case with you but I just thought to share the my experience for the same kind of error so that anyone coming to this thread can benefit from it.

Thanks.